# GNU C++: why custom class can not be value type for unordered_map?

Tags: c++, gcc, unordered-map

I have simple code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A(void)
    {
    }
    A(const A &other)
    {
    }
    A &operator=(const A &other)
    {
        return *this;
    }
    A(const unordered_map<int, A> &value)
    {
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    A a;
    unordered_map<wstring, A> m;
    printf("Hello, World!");
    return 0;
}
```

For any reason, GNU C++ 4.8.2 can not compile it and shows a lot of errors; I see that it "dislikes" the constructor `A(const unordered_map<int, A> &value)`. What is the reason? MSVC compiler compiles such code without problems. Are there any C++ limitations on `unordered_map` value types that has constructors that accept another `unordered_map` instances?

Comment: Could you reduce the code to a simple test case? It's impossible to guess what might be wrong from a description like this. As far as I can guess from the errors, `GoodGuySoft::Dynamic` doesn't have the copy constructor you describe.

Comment: Post the code of the object class in question. A properly equipped class can easily be a value-type of any map class, unordered or otherwise. If not your code, then *any* code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Full code depends on near 10 other classes; when I reduce it, the error is not reproduced. `GoodGuySoft::Dynamic` for sure has copy constructor with following prototype: `Dynamic(const Dynamic &other)` The error is something very specific I think; when I remove from the code any methods except constructor, destructor and assignments, it compiles; so it looks like the fact that some methods exist breaks GNU C++ templates.

Comment: Why tag both visual C++ and gcc? From what it sounds like, it compiles in visual C++ but not gcc. Usually, you'd want to post the code in question so others can diagnose where the error in your code lies, rather than assuming the fault lies in the compiler. If it's a compiler bug, that's where you come in with a test case so people can analyze if it's a compiler bug or just a problem with your code.

Comment: For remyabel: I posted in a hope that anyone else ported code from MSVC to GCC and knows the solution already.

Comment: @VASoftOnline In my unfounded experience, it's usually MSVC that's the buggy compiler and/or has extensions that allows code to compile that otherwise would not compile in gcc. Considering it's most likely a fault in your code (because you were able to reduce it and not reproduce the error) then there's no reason to tag both compilers.

Comment: Well, I reproduced it in small code.

Comment: Sweet. Hopefully its the same issue and we can help track it down. Edit: Thanks for the update. clang 3.3 eats that up without a problem, just fyi.

Comment: Fwiw, also works with gcc v4.7.2 with `g++ -std=c++11`

Comment: So it may be bug, who knows. With GCC 4.8.2 command `g++ -std=c++11 build/test.cpp -o ../obj/test.o` gives a lot of errors on that code.

Comment: In case you want to see it live (broken). I believe ideone.com uses 4.8.2 as well, and [here it is in all its tragedy](http://ideone.com/QFAtmD). Removing the unordered_map reference constructor allows it to pass, in case you didn't already know.

Comment: Yes, I see the same messages in my compilation too. Last is not always the best, will try to downgrade to 4.7.

Comment: I've compiled with both clang 3.5 trunk and gcc 4.8.1 here, it seems a issue with library. The code compiles fine with clang with libc++, but it does not compile with clang, nor with gcc, using libstdc++.

Comment: Well, I just noticed that one of the errors complain about incomplete type, because of your constructor. If you change it to `A(const unordered_map<int, A*> &value) {}`, it compiles for me.

Comment: As an absolutely hideous work-around you could SFINAE a template constructor around `std::unordered_map<int,T>` enabled only on `std::is_same<T,A>::value`. I just tried it and shockingly it worked (a rarity for me and SFINAE first-time-around). So take that for what its worth.

Comment: clang shows it more clearly that the problem arises from `std::is_convertible` from stdlibc++ for that type: http://pastebin.com/C9mFPb3v

Comment: @remyabel: Interesting observation, If declaring a map requires the value type to be a complete type, that would mean that the errors are correct, and all the compilers compiling this code are wrong!

Comment: @MooingDuck declaring a "std::map" give no issues, just so you know, I mean, just changing one map type for the other in the code.

Comment: Regarding the [sfinae workaround](http://ideone.com/xvikRO) mentioned earlier. pfft. like I said, yuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most probably a stdlibc++ bug, in the version you're using.

I'm on ubuntu using gcc 4.8.1, and clang 3.5 trunk. With clang using libc++ there's no problem. With both clang and gcc using libstdc++ the issue is triggered.

For the following simpler main function, the same problem is triggered for your type:

```
int main() {
    using namespace std;
    cout << is_convertible<const A &, A>::value << endl;
}
```

Also, changing from using `std::unordered_map` to `std::map`, there's no issue.

This is the *much nicer* clang error log:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/type_traits:117:14: error: base class has incomplete type
    : public conditional<_B1::value, _B2, _B1>::type
      ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_pair.h:122:19: note: in instantiation of template class
      'std::__and_<std::is_convertible<const int &, const int>, std::is_convertible<const A &, A> >' requested here
               enable_if<__and_<is_convertible<const _U1&, _T1>,
                         ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_pair.h:124:12: note: in instantiation of default argument for
      'pair<const int, A>' required here
        constexpr pair(const pair<_U1, _U2>& __p)
                  ^~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_pair.h:124:12: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into
      function template 'pair' [with _U1 = const int, _U2 = A, $2 = <no value>]
        constexpr pair(const pair<_U1, _U2>& __p)
                  ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/type_traits:803:24: note: in instantiation of default argument for
      '__test<std::pair<const int, A>, const std::pair<const int, A> &>' required here
      static true_type __test(int);
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/type_traits:803:24: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into
      function template '__test' [with _Tp = std::pair<const int, A>, _Arg = const std::pair<const int, A> &, $2 = <no value>]
      static true_type __test(int);
                       ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/type_traits:117:14: note: (skipping 10 contexts in backtrace; use
      -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
    : public conditional<_B1::value, _B2, _B1>::type
             ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/bits/unordered_map.h:97:27: note: in instantiation of template type alias
      '__check_copy_constructible' requested here
    class unordered_map : __check_copy_constructible<_Alloc>
                          ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/type_traits:1305:42: note: in instantiation of template class
      'std::unordered_map<int, A, std::hash<int>, std::equal_to<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, A> > >' requested here
        static decltype(__test_aux<_To1>(std::declval<_From1>()), __one())
                                         ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/type_traits:1306:2: note: while substituting explicitly-specified template
      arguments into function template '__test'
        __test(int);
        ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/type_traits:1319:11: note: in instantiation of template class
      'std::__is_convertible_helper<const A &, A, false>' requested here
                               __is_convertible_helper<_From, _To>::value>
                               ^
c++1y-sample.cpp:33:13: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::is_convertible<const A &, A>' requested here
    cout << is_convertible<const A &, A>::value << endl;
            ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/type_traits:1317:12: note: definition of 'std::is_convertible<const A &, A>' is
      not complete until the closing '}'
    struct is_convertible
```